# Scala Spark : Is there a datafu.pig.sampling.SampleByKey alternative in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-pig

SampleByKey's method of sampling is to convert the key to a hash, derive a double value
from this, and then test this against a supplied probability.  The double value
derived from a key is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Code [Link](https://github.com/apache/datafu/blob/master/datafu-pig/src/main/java/datafu/pig/sampling/SampleByKey.java).
All the rows which have the same key, gets sampled this way.

I have a Dataframe which is formed by performing union operation on multiple dataframe (they all have the same schema). What I'm interested to do is, each individual dataframe has a `column X`, and say a value `y` present in it. This value `y` will be present in few other dataframe's too. If I sample this dataframe, either individually or post union, how can I make sure that the data that got sampled consists of all the data that had value `y` present in `column X` ? Similar to how the SampleByKey works.

I went through the `sample` API of DataFrame's but seems like it doesn't work this way.
Can someone help here !

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of `stratified sampling`. Spark has more powerful sampling algorithm implemented

1. Poisson Sampling Algo
2. Bernoulli Sampling Algo

You can convert your `dataframe` to `RDD[(K, V)]` aka `PairRDD` and then you can use pair rdd function `sampleByKey`, check this [source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L253)-

```
  def sampleByKey(withReplacement: Boolean,
      fractions: Map[K, Double],
      seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): RDD[(K, V)]
```

For more info- [spark stratified sampling](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/mllib-statistics.html#stratified-sampling)

To get all the rows having `y` from column `x`

```
// specify the exact fraction desired from each key
val fractions = Map("y" -> 1)// for all rows 1, for 50% rows use 0.5 etc.

// Get an exact sample from each stratum
// here data is RDD[(x, <any_other_col>)]
val exactSample = data.sampleByKeyExact(withReplacement = false, fractions = fractions)
```